# Trying to figure out how to push specific links contained in each link of separate list of links into an array

Tags: arrays, perl, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-treebuilder

---

### GENERAL IDEA

---

Here is a snippet of what I'm working with:

```
my $url_temp;
my $page_temp;
my $p_temp;
my @temp_stuff;
my @collector;

foreach (@blarg_links) {
        $url_temp = $_;
        $page_temp = get( $url_temp ) or die $!;
        $p_temp = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $page_temp );
        @temp_stuff = $p_temp->look_down(
                _tag => 'foo',
                class => 'bar'
        );
        foreach (@temp_stuff) {
                push(@collector, "http://www.foobar.sx" . $1) if $_->as_HTML =~ m/href="(.*?)"/;
        };
};
```

Hopefully it is clear that what I'm hopelessly trying to do is push the link endings found in each of a list of links into an array called `@temp_stuff`. So the first link in `@blarg_links`, when visited, has greater than or equal to 1 `foo` tag with an associated `bar` class that when acted on by `as_HTML` will match something I want in the `href` equality to then pump into an array of links which have the data I'm really after... Does that make sense?

---

### ACTUAL DATA

---

```
my $url2 = 'http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/year';
my $page2 = get( $url2 ) or die $!;
my $p2 = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $page2 );

my @stuff2 = $p2->look_down(
        _tag => 'div',
        class => 'year mini-day-on'
);

my @chem_links;

foreach (@stuff2) {
        push(@chem_links, $1) if $_->as_HTML =~ m/(http:\/\/www\.chemistry\.ucla\.edu\/calendar-node-field-date\/day\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/;
};

my $url_temp;
my $page_temp;
my $p_temp;
my @temp_stuff;
my @collector;

foreach (@chem_links) {
        $url_temp = $_;
        $page_temp = get( $url_temp ) or die $!;
        $p_temp = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $page_temp );
        @temp_stuff = $p_temp->look_down(
                _tag => 'span',
                class => 'field-content'
        );
};

foreach (@temp_stuff) {
                push(@collector, "http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu" . $1) if $_->as_HTML =~ m/href="(.*?)"/;
};
```

---

*n.b.* - I want to use HTML::TreeBuilder. I'm aware of alternatives.

---

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to use `HTML::TreeBuilder` to extract the values of the `href` attributes instead of dumping the contents of each element as HTML and falling back ro a regex to do it. But I can't help unless you show the real HTML.

Comment: I want to _understand_ any answer given here, so, please, if you don't mind, leave helpful comments for me.

Comment: Instead of doing your own extraction with HTML::TreeBuilder, take a look at WWW::Mechanize which does it for you.

Comment: @AndyLester Do I have to install anything?

Comment: @AndyLester: `WWW::Mechanize` doesn't do anything to make finding links like this easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough attempt at what I think you want.

It fetches all the links on the first page and visits each of them in turn, printing the link in each `<span class="field-content">` element.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $url = 'http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/year';
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url);

my @chem_links;

for my $div ( $tree->look_down( _tag => 'div', class => qr{\bmini-day-on\b} ) ) {
  my ($anchor)= $div->look_down(_tag => 'a', href => qr{http://www\.chemistry\.ucla\.edu});
  push @chem_links, $anchor->attr('href');
};

my @collector;

for my $url (@chem_links) {

  say $url;

  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url);

  my @seminars;

  for my $span ( $tree->look_down( _tag => 'span', class => 'field-content' ) ) {
    my ($anchor) = $span->look_down(_tag => 'a', href => qr{/});
    push @seminars, 'http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu'.$anchor->attr('href');
  }

  say "  $_" for @seminars;
  say '';

  push @collector, @seminars;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more modern framework for parsing webpages, I would suggest you take a look at [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) and [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM).  Instead of having to manually march through each section of your html tree, you can use the power of [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to zero in on the specific data that you want.  There's a nice 8 minute introductory video on the framework at [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

```
# Parses the UCLA Chemistry Calendar and displays all seminar links

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use URI;

my $url = 'http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/year';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = $ua->get($url)->res->dom;

for my $dayhref ($dom->find('div.mini-day-on > a[href*="/day/"]')->attr('href')->each) {
    my $dayurl = URI->new($dayhref)->abs($url);
    print $dayurl, "\n";

    my $daydom = $ua->get($dayurl->as_string)->res->dom;
    for my $seminarhref ($daydom->find('span.field-content > a[href]')->attr('href')->each) {
        my $seminarurl = URI->new($seminarhref)->abs($dayurl);
        print "  $seminarurl\n";
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

Output is identical to that of [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046977/1733163) using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder):

```
http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/day/2014-01-06
  http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/seminars/nano-rheology-enzymes

http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/day/2014-01-09
  http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/seminars/imaging-approach-biology-disease-through-chemistry

http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/day/2014-01-10
  http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/seminars/arginine-methylation-%E2%80%93-substrates-binders-function
  http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/seminars/special-inorganic-chemistry-seminar

http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/calendar-node-field-date/day/2014-01-13
  http://www.chemistry.ucla.edu/events/robert-l-scott-lecture-0

...
```